# How to change svg color in loop in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a application in wordpress with angular js cdn. But the problem is that i am trying to apply color on svg according to loop value.I already make a function for that but the issue is that when i pass the value in the function and trying to add css using jquery it is not working. I don't have much knowledge about angular js.

Comment: The question is not clear: do you use AngularJS or Angular ? You are using jQuery too ? You should definitely show some code

Answer (score 0):

When you use `angularJS`, you no longer need to use `JQuery`. You can manage all your operations and paint your HTML by defining the function inside the HTML.

angular is client side framework for MVC pattern to manage data in defined controllers and specified scopes. read this doc [AngularJS Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Dear";
  $scope.dataColor = [
    {color: "red"}, 
    {color: "blue"}, 
    {color: "yellow"}, 
    {color: "black"}
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <svg height="30" width="200" ng-repeat="x in dataColor">
  <text x="0" y="15" fill={{x.color}}>I love stackOverFlow!</text>
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```